# Android: Google Maps not loading

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a mapsActivity that don't load correctly. The Api key is well
configured because if I call to maps activity after the splashScreen everything works OK. My emulator has installed api 26

This is the log when I call Mapsactivity after splashScreen.

```
>     I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 22048
>     I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
>     I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
>           adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.lyntia.android.mera
>     D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
>     D/SplashScreenActivity: User has logged in, token OK
>     V/FA: onActivityCreated
>     I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 15298(1332KB) AllocSpace objects, 11(220KB) LOS >objects, 55% free, 1238KB/2MB,
> paused 2.344ms total 101.117ms
>     V/FA: Connecting to remote service
>     V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>     I/zzbz: Making Creator dynamically
>     W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
>     I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module
> com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:221
>         Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 221
>     V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
>     V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>     W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
>     I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=22KB
>         After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=22KB
>     I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
>     I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
>     I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 16089022
>     I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=52KB, data=38KB
>     I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=52KB, data=38KB
>         Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
>     D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null
>     V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 3535145
>     I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
>     D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
>     I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=83KB, data=87KB
>     D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa3a7c440, tid 15830
>     I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>     D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
>     I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=81KB, data=65KB
>     W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
>     D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
>     D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa63060a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
>     V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>     V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>     D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa63060a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x88213db0)
>     E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
>     D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x932f0040, tid 15826
>     D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa6305920: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
>     D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa63060a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x88213db0)
>     D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6305920: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0x92ef6900)
>     D/FA: Connected to remote service
>     V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 5
>     I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=111KB, data=97KB
>     I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=102KB, data=92KB
>     I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
>     W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not >found.
>     I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote >module
> com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
>         Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
>     W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
>     V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
>     I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=240KB, data=192KB
>         After code cache collection, code=208KB, data=138KB
>     I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=245KB, data=187KB
>     I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=245KB, data=187KB
>         Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
```

This is the log when I call mapsActivity in they correct place (Don't work).

```
  D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3de7c80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa3918900)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3de7c80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa3918900)
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 1649
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 671631
V/FA: onActivityCreated
I/zygote: JIT allocated 56KB for compiled code of void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
I/zzbz: Making Creator dynamically
W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:221
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 221
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 16089022
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 672047
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9157a5c0, tid 7910
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x911c7740: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3de7c80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa3918900)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x911c7740: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0x90eec950)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3de7c80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa3918900)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3de7c80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa3918900)
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=471KB, data=305KB
    After code cache collection, code=467KB, data=235KB
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=495KB, data=276KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=495KB, data=276KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 2MB
```

activity_maps.xml

```
<fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3" />
```

MapsActivity.java

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

androidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".MeraApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Before mapsactivity there are some activities that get and post data from/to the server.
I don't know if it can be a problem with memory, cache...

Any help?

Comment: Please edit your post and point out where the specific problem is

Comment: Do you call Maps Activity from another activity? If so, can you also please share how you are calling MapsActivity from this other activity? It would also help if you could provide a small reproducible sample of your issue.